# Issue using .erb to display date with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I am using ruby .erb to display time in a div's span. However using something similar for date does not work.

```
<div id="comment_space">
  <% @post.comments.each_with_index do |comment,date,posted,index| %> 
    <span class="above"><%= date = ('%Y-%m-%d') %> </span> 
    <div   class="comment"     id="msg_<%= index+1 %>"> 
      <%= comment.usr_comment %>
      <span class="right">
        <%= comment.created_at.localtime.strftime("%l: %M %p") %>
      </span> 
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <span class="above">
    <%= date = ('%Y-%m-%d') %> 
  </span>
```

This is the part not working. However

```
<span class="right">
  <%= comment.created_at.localtime.strftime("%l: %M %p") %>
</span>
```

works perfectly.

The first error was that "created_at" was not lked for the date and it has gone down hill from there. The date and time were defined in Javascript with timestamps in a Ruby ActiveRecord table.

Comment: Please don't write the question in the title. Find a suitable title and put the question in its right place.

Comment: @ed thanks for the tip! Still getting a hang of the site, I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= date = ('%Y-%m-%d') %>  # Ehhhhhm
```

Ok, compare that to your other way of doing this.

```
<%= comment.created_at.localtime.strftime("%l: %M %p") %>
```

See the difference?
If the "date" is Date class, you can do:

```
<%= date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>
```

and it should work with no problem whatsoever.

If you do what you did, you say that the date is now '%Y-%m-%d'

```
date = ('%Y-%m-%d')
# => "%Y-%m-%d"
```

Comment: great advice, thanks so much it works perfectly now!